# React App becomes slow after long usage in safari

Tags: reactjs, safari, react-spring

I'm running a learning app written in react. The average session duration is 15 Minutes. Recently some Safari users (mobile and desktop) reported that the apps feels laggy after a fair bit of use (answering questions).

I monitored memory used in safari and answered some questions in the app. After a while, there is a spike in page memory usage (a ridiculous amount). A minute later page memory goes up again and stays there. From there on the app feels quite laggy.
[image: Safari Memory Usage]

The vast majority of javascript events are `Animation Frame Requested` and `Animation Frame Fired` events. That's why I thought that animations may be the culprit. I'm using react-spring and found this open [issue](https://github.com/pmndrs/react-spring/issues/1085).

I can only run safari in a docker container on my Linux machine, as I don't have an apple device (https://github.com/sickcodes/Docker-OSX). Maybe that is the reason for the weirdly high amount of page memory usage (I wish I had that amount of RAM).

I'm kind of stuck and don't know how to proceed. Did anyone experience similar issues with react, react-spring and safari?